# Add Lead related products to opportunity related products after converting

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

1. Identifying if the lead is converted
2. Which opportunity it is getting converted to. --> ConvertedOpportunityId
3. Query on all the products added at lead related list.
4. Create same products at Opportunity.

I want help with step 4, in adding the products to opportunity. How can I acheive that?

```
trigger AddProductsfromLead2Opp on Lead (after update) {
    Set<Id> OppId = new Set<ID>();
    List<Opportunity> Opp2Update = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    List<Lead_Product__c> lp = new List<Lead_Product__c>();

    //check if the lead is created
    for(Lead l:Trigger.new){
        /* Getting Opportunity Ids from the Lead after conversion .
           ConvertedOpportunityId in Lead contains the Opportunity Id to which the Lead is converted.
        */
        if(l.isConverted){
            OppId.add(l.ConvertedOpportunityId);
        }

        if(OppId.size() > 0){
             lp = [select id,Product__c, Lead__c from Lead_Product__c where Lead__c = :l.id];
            system.debug(lp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to sfse. Note that your trigger is not bulkified as you are doing a SOQL query inside a for loop. Read up on Trailhead and in apex doc on how to use maps

Comment: Thank you cropredy. 
I will look into it. 
Meanwhile can you help me out with the above question ?
How can i approach it ?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to bulkify this code first as it will provide insight into how to solve the requirement